# OAuth on the Front end

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth

I am new to web development and I am trying to access the github API using just front end of html/css/js.

The documentation specifies that I need an OAuth token. Is there any way for me to do this?

https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Thank you.

Comment: For local purposes yes. However, everybody that has got your code can extract the token and do bulshit in your name. So dont publish it

Comment: So, it's not possible to use only front-end to authenticate GitHub user? Facebook can do that.